# How can I make threejs canvas NOT to be resized by keyboard

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, canvas, three.js, keyboard

This appears with iOs (iPad).

I'm using Three.js in an Ionic v1 app and I have this issue : when I open the keyboard, the canvas that hosts Three.js is reduced, but when I close the keyboard the canvas stays in this state, it isn't resized to it's original size, so I have a big white space between canvas' bottom and bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to say to keyboard's plugin to cover the content and not pushing it ? Or a way to resize the canvas after hiding keyboard ?

Thanks by advance.

Ps : other issue, perhaps in relation : the canvas is note resized when I rotate the screen. I'm using THREEx.WindowResize(), that works perfectly in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution : the issue is du to the iOs animation duration when showing the keyboard or rotating the screen. I added a $timeout on resizing function to make it wait for animation end before trigger resizing.